# NullPointer when adding to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I realize there are already a bunch of questions like this but every one I have seen so far the problem was the ArrayList was not initialized.  I think mine is initialized but I get a NullPointer when trying to add to the list.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Deck {
    static final int DECKSIZE = 48;
    static final int MAX = 10;
    static final int MIN = 1;
    public ArrayList<Card> cardDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();
    Random rand;

    public Deck() {
        initializeDeck();
    }

    private void initializeDeck() {
        for (int i=0; i<DECKSIZE; i++) {
            cardDeck.add(i, new Card("Name" + (i+1),  "Race" + (i+1), "Orientation" + (i+1)));
        }
    }

    public void shuffleCards() {
        Collections.shuffle(cardDeck);
    }
}
```

Here is stack trace telling me initializeDeck is a nullPointer

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hr.krypto.cardwars.deck.Deck.initializeDeck(Deck.java:24)
    at hr.krypto.cardwars.deck.Deck.<init>(Deck.java:15)
    at hr.krypto.cardwars.deck.Dealer.<init>(Dealer.java:14)
    at hr.krypto.cardwars.model.CardTable.<init>(CardTable.java:15)
    at hr.krypto.cardwars.screen.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:31)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:62)
    at hr.krypto.cardwars.CardWarsGame.create(CardWarsGame.java:19)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:127)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:110)
```

Comment: please post stacktrace

Comment: The stacktrace should indicate where you have a problem.

Comment: @Keyser this method can throw only `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Please show us the constructor of Card

Comment: cardDeck.add(i - Don't add at an index position, just add (to the end)

Comment: Also initialise your ArrayList to the correct size: new ArrayList<Card>(DECKSIZE);

Comment: `<offtopic>`Shouldn't there be 52 cards in the deck?`</offtopic>`

Comment: Well there's no point, you aren't doing insertions you're adding to a list so you'll only increase you chance of an IndexOutOfBoundsException or just make your code harder to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the constructor `Card(String, String, String)` a NullPointerException is raised.
As shown by the stacktrace with line number.

If an other constructor `Card()` does some initialisation, simply first call `this()` inside the added constructor.

---

***After the stack trace was added:***

**Correction**.
I bet in the ran code still `rand` is used, which is not initialized (null). Do a clean first before building.

Or there are two classes Deck in different packages, is the shown class in `package hr.krypto.cardwars.deck;`?

Comment: You posted the answer before a `StackTrace` was actually posted by the OP. Amazing!

Comment: @StefanBe you are right, I am turning into a puzzler. Here it is an unavoidable conclusion though. As the shown code is basically correct.

Comment: Both your answer and TwoMore's answer helped point me in the right direction.  rand was not initialized

Comment: @tomislav2012 please show us the constructor I am so curious about the problem :)

Comment: no need to post Card class, i was populating Card class with rand values from Deck, and rand was not initialized.  Code runs fine now.  Thanks SO!!!!! you rock

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the method `ArrayList.add(index, Element)` only throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` the error must be in the constructor of your card class.

Guess the fastest way would be to debug into the card class constructor.

Comment: @Henrik your right, but considering that it happends on the add methode, whcih has only an int and element parameter doesnt leave much place where an error can occure other that in the constructor of the new object. therefor just debugging.